# How to create a technical texture?

Tags: texturing

I recently modelled a music mixing panel (the one in the reference picture below). But now my work in Blender (modelling, unwrapping, shading,...) is done and I need to create the textures (such as the indicators for volume and labels for buttons). I don't have any paid software like Photoshop, but I use GIMP instead. however these kind of drawings seem to be a problem in GIMP (like drawing a line and duplicating it multiple times like the array modifier would do in Blender).

Are there any free programs that make this job easier? I was thinking of using paint or google drawings if I don't find any other software, but that would really be a pain to get it all right. If it is possible in GIMP than also please let me now how...

[image: mixing panel]

Comment: Looks like the job for a vector illustration application like [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org). You could export as a large texture or import the SVG vector file directly into Blender. You can also model those directly in blender as a mix of text objects a bezier curves, if you don't need to export a textured model

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into inkscape. But how would I do it directly in Blender?

Comment: It looks mostly like white text over a background, so use text objects with a very small bevel factor, or slight extrude. Use bezier curves for non text elements